# Compose Card shadow behavior when inside a column

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, shadow

The shadow of my card is behaving irregular based on the properties of the column it is wrapped in.

When I set verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom, I get a nice, distinct shadow under the card.

But if no arrangement is set at all the shadow is just a barely visible outline. Why is this?

The project is using androidx.compose.material:material:1.8.0

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestCardPreview() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        TestCard()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestCard() {
    Card(
        Modifier.padding(30.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(50.dp),
            text = "CardTest"
        )
    }
}
```

[with verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom, shadow showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK9l0.png)

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestCardPreview() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        TestCard()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestCard() {
    Card(
        Modifier.padding(30.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(50.dp),
            text = "CardTest"
        )
    }
}
```

[With no verticalArrangement set, missing bottom shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuD5F.png)

Comment: That is very interesting. Did you double-check that besides the `verticalArrangement` property, the code is exactly the same in both screenshots? Did you also try it on a physical device or only the emulator?